# What mark up language is there for Mac Os developers?

Tags: macos, programming-languages, markup

- So Adobe gives GIVES US mxml FOR AIR ( Flash )
  design/development (cross platform,
  ActionScript)
- Microsoft gives us XAML for .Net
  design/development (Windows, Silverlight, C# + VB+ F# +...)
- What mark up language gives us Apple
  for design/development of our Mac
  native apps?!?

Comment: Just an aside, you could use XAML for Silverlight on the OSX, but I realize you are asking about naitive apps.  Interesting question!

Comment: When you figure it out, let me know if there's a similar one for oranges, since my gums don't get along as well with the peel on apples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called `nib` (older version) or `xib` (more recent, XML version) and you can edit it using [Interface Builder](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).
People don't usually view them as markup languages, because conceptually the file describes a freeze-dried GUI objects rather than a markup language describing the GUI.  But it fills the same position as them.